# Google Sheets ARRAYFORMULA working only if the first cell in a column is TRUE

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I have the following formula in a cell

=IF(ARRAYFORMULA(B4:B=FALSE),"Total: 0",CONCATENATE("Total: ",(REGEXEXTRACT(D2,"\d+.\d*"))+(REGEXEXTRACT(D1,"\d+.\d+"))))

B4:B is a column with checkboxes.

This formula is in a cell that should show the sum of two cells, D1 and D2 if any of the checkboxes in the B4:B range is checked TRUE, or show "Total: 0" if NONE of the checkboxes in B4:B are checked. However, currently it is showing "Total: 0" unless the checkbox in B4 is checked TRUE, regardless of the value TRUE of other checkboxes in B5:B. The goal is that it shows the sum of  D1 and D2 if ANY checkbox is checked TRUE.

Could you please help?
Thanks

I tried =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B4:B=FALSE),"Total: 0",CONCATENATE("Total: ",(REGEXEXTRACT(D2,"\d+.\d*"))+(REGEXEXTRACT(D1,"\d+.\d+"))))

But it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

The following formula returns an array of booleans:

```cpp
ARRAYFORMULA(B4:B=FALSE)
```

And

```cpp
IF(array_of_booleans, ...)
```

Only checks the first value of the array because `IF` is not an array enabling function.

To accomplish this:

> The formula should show the sum of two cells, D1 and D2 if any of the checkboxes in the B4:B range is checked TRUE, or show "Total: 0" if NONE of the checkboxes in B4:B are checked.

You can use the [`OR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093306?hl=en) function:

```cpp
=IF(OR(B4:B),D1+D2,"Total: 0")
```